Conditionally select value based on value-boolean column pairs
I have the following sample:
var_1 <- c("1", "15", "35", "abc")
var_1_is_deleted <- c("Yes", "No", "No", "Yes")
var_2 <- c("xyz", NA, NA, "sos")
var_2_is_deleted <- c("No", NA, NA, "Yes")
var_3 <- c(NA, NA, "hello", "def")
var_3_is_deleted <- c(NA, NA, "Yes", "No")

df <- data.frame(var_1, var_1_is_deleted, var_2, var_2_is_deleted, var_3, var_3_is_deleted)

df
  var_1 var_1_is_deleted var_2 var_2_is_deleted var_3 var_3_is_deleted
1     1              Yes   xyz               No  <NA>             <NA>
2    15               No  <NA>             <NA>  <NA>             <NA>
3    35               No  <NA>             <NA> hello              Yes
4   abc              Yes   sos              Yes   def               No


The number of var_x columns is not fixed, it varies between 1 and 9 depending on the dataframe I'm working with.
I would like to create a new column containing the first var_x value for which the corresponding var_x_is_deleted equals to No, like so:
  var_1 var_1_is_deleted var_2 var_2_is_deleted var_3 var_3_is_deleted **var**
1     1              Yes   xyz               No  <NA>             <NA> **xyz**
2    15               No  <NA>             <NA>  <NA>             <NA> **15**
3    35               No  <NA>             <NA> hello              Yes **35**
4   abc              Yes   sos              Yes   def               No **def**

How can I achieve this result either with base R or using Tidyverse packages?

I think this is a question which is best answered via tidyr::pivot_longer() (or reshape()) using a clever names_pattern.
However, I wanted to show a different solution which assumes that the data frame (df0) is ordered and every two columns belong to a var_\\d+, i.e. ncol(df0) needs to be a multiple of 2.
Reshape df0 to long format (named dfl):

dfl = split.default(df0, ceiling(seq_along(df0) / 2L)) |>
  lapply(\(x) transform(x, v = names(x)[1]) |> 
           setNames(c("val", "del", "var"))) |> 
  do.call(what="rbind")

Overhead due to (re-)naming columns in each iteration.
Then, use by() to identify first occurence of del=="No", index val accordingly. Finally, coerce to character and assign to df0 (initial wide data frame).
df0$flag = as.character(by(dfl, rep(seq(nrow(df0)), times = ncol(df0)/2L), 
                           with, val[min(Position(isTRUE, del=="No"))]))

giving
> df0  
  var_1 var_1_is_deleted var_2 var_2_is_deleted var_3 var_3_is_deleted flag
1     1              Yes   xyz               No  <NA>             <NA>  xyz
2    15               No  <NA>             <NA>  <NA>             <NA>   15
3    35               No  <NA>             <NA> hello              Yes   35
4   abc              Yes   sos              Yes   def               No  def

That was fun.

Note
This answer is sensitive to it's assumptions. It has some overhead. I renamed your toy data to df0. I do not use df to name data objects, cp. ?stats::df.

Edit
Addressing your comment
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df0 |>
  mutate(id = row_number(), .before = 1) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("deleted"), names_to = "pos", names_prefix = "var", values_to = "val") |>
  mutate(pos = as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", pos))) |>
  filter(val=="No") |>
  filter(pos == min(pos), .by = id) |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(flag = paste(c(var_1, var_2, var_3))[pos]) |> 
  pull(flag) 


Thanks for the tip about tidyr::pivot_longer() and for the remark regarding df. I managed to find a slightly less elegant solution than yours using tidyr::pivot_longer() and will share it soon.

in base R you can use max.col:
index <- max.col(df == 'No'&!is.na(df),ties.method = 'first') - 1
cbind(df, var = df[cbind(seq(nrow(df)), index)])

  var_1 var_1_is_deleted var_2 var_2_is_deleted var_3 var_3_is_deleted var
1     1              Yes   xyz               No  <NA>             <NA> xyz
2    15               No  <NA>             <NA>  <NA>             <NA>  15
3    35               No  <NA>             <NA> hello              Yes  35
4   abc              Yes   sos              Yes   def               No def

